# How to get the value of an input?

Tags: javascript, html, input

today I'm working on a practice, but I encountered a question:

```
<button class="show">
  show lyrics
</button>
<label for="artist">artist</label>
<input type="text" id="artist">
<label for="song">songName</label>
<input type="text" id="song" >
```

I type in the artist and song into the input area, then
I want to get the value of the input, so I write like these:

```
let show = document.querySelector('.show')
let artistName = document.querySelector('#artist').value
let songName = document.querySelector('#song').value
show.addEventListener("click", function(){
  console.log("artist: ", artistName, "song: ", songName )  /// "" ""
})
```

but  I found that it's not working, only if I write like these will do:

```
let artistName = document.querySelector('#artist')
let songName = document.querySelector('#song')

show.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log(artistName.value , songName.value ) /// "artist: " "coldplay" "song: " "yellow"
})
```

I don't know the reason, is it because the querySelector only show the Node ?

Comment: It's because you need to get the value at the time of the click. With your first version, you get the value only once, at startup.

Comment: `let artistName = document.querySelector('#artist').value` is evaluated on the page startup, and never refreshed. You are assigning the string to the variable, and in JavaScript strings are immutable

Answer (score -1):

You have to read the value on 'click' listener too.
Also, your code is not wrapped in 'DOMContentLoaded' event listener and JS might fire before HTML is ready.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  //...your code
})
```

Comment: Then it would not have printed anything on click.

Comment: ...and what they said worked at the end of the question wouldn't have worked. If this *were* the problem, it would be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element). Also, in modern environments, `DOMContentLoaded` is really not necessary. Just use modules, or `defer` on the `script`. (In fact, it was almost never needed outside libraries; you could just put the `script` at the end of the HTML.)